# Confusion of return value(s) in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I am not quite familiar with Python, I got this problems in code as following, does anyone help me to explain why?

```py
def caller1(a):
  return 'a' if a < 11 else 'a', 'b'

print(caller1(a=5))

def caller2(a):
  if a < 11:
    return 'a'
  else:
    return 'a', 'b'

print(caller2(a=5))

c = caller2(a=5)
print(c)
```

for caller1 I expect output 'a' but print ('a', 'b')

for caller2 will print 'a', but eventually print ('a', 'b') (at least per my debug will show the ('a', 'b') result, both 'a' and ('a', 'b') will print out).

why will happen like this?

Comment: `return 'a' if a < 11 else 'a', 'b'` can be written as `return 'a' if a < 11 else ('a', 'b')` if it makes it any more clearer

Comment: For `caller2`, *"...but eventually print ('a', 'b')"*. No it won't. It just prints `'a'`.

Comment: @Austin running in console you'll see the 'a' but if have context for using returning value they shows 'a' and ('a', 'b') and my question is caller1 and caller2 are doing the same thing why have different result, do you notice that?

Comment: "for caller1 I expect output 'a' " why? What do you think happens to ``'b'``?

Comment: @Wilson The two are *not* equivalent. The ternary ``if`` binds *stronger* than ``,``. ``caller1`` executes ``('a' if a < 11 else 'a'), 'b'``.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Result:

Output of caller1 function is ('a', 'b') instead of a.

#### Reason:

In the line

```
  return 'a' if a < 11 else 'a', 'b'
```

Else condition only contains 'a' and not 'a', 'b'. 'b' is comma separated from the if/else condition.

So the function returns 'a' (as a < 11 is true) followed by 'b'.

#### Solution:

Replace with below line to achieve the desired result.

```
  return 'a' if a < 11 else ('a', 'b')
```